# Prevent ListView Row Disappearing Upon Data Update

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview that displays message items.  When the parent window is open, it starts a timer that checks every xx amount to see if any new messages have been sent.  This then clears the listview control and rebuilds it everytime (not sure if this is the best way).

Anyway, if the mouse is sitting over the top of a listview item when the listview gets rebuilt, the listview row is blank.  However, moving the mouse off the item and back on the item will redraw it fine.

The code to build my listview is such:

```
Private Sub LoadMessages()
    Dim QueryString As String

    Try
        lsvMail.Items.Clear()
        QueryString = "SELECT * FROM Mail WHERE recipient = '" & Current_User.DisplayName & "' ORDER BY sent DESC"
        Dim ExQry As New MySqlCommand(QueryString, MySQLConn)

        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(ExQry)
        da.Fill(dsMessages, "Messages")
        Dim tempDT As DataTable = dsMessages.Tables("Messages")

        If dsMessages.Tables.Count > 0 And dsMessages.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For x = 0 To (dsMessages.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
                Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(tempDT.Rows(x)("is_replied").ToString)
                lvi.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("sender").ToString)

                If CBool(tempDT.Rows(x)("is_read")) = True Then
                    lvi.Font = RegularFont
                Else
                    lvi.Font = BoldFont
                End If

                If CBool(tempDT.Rows(x)("is_followup")) = True Then
                    lvi.ForeColor = Color.Red
                Else
                    lvi.ForeColor = Color.Black
                End If

                lvi.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("subject").ToString)
                lvi.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("sent").ToString)
                lvi.SubItems.Add(tempDT.Rows(x)("is_followup").ToString)
                lvi.Name = tempDT.Rows(x)("id").ToString
                lsvMail.Items.Add(lvi)
            Next
        End If
        da = Nothing
        tempDT = Nothing
        dsMessages.Clear()

    Catch ex As Exception
        CreateLog("Module: LoadMailMessages()" & vbNewLine & "Exception Error: " & ex.Message)
        MsgBox("Exception Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Module: LoadMailMessages()")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Like mentioned, I have a timer event that simply calls the LoadMessages() routine.
I am trying to have a 'live' feed to the messages window so that new items will appear in the listview if the window is open.

Any help appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding refresh:

```
    Next
    lvi.Refresh()
End If
```

Comment: lvi is the listview item and does not support the .refresh command.  I have tried adding the refresh to the lsvMail but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Just to be sure try invalidating entire form as well.

Comment: I have tried both Me.invalidate and lsvMail.invalidate but both cause no change.  If the listview control is owner drawn, will that make a difference?